# Why the original list is also getting sorted in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Python Version used: Python **3.11.3**

Code :

```
original_list= [4, 2, 0, 3, 1]

duplicate_list=original_list
duplicate_list.sort()

print(original_list)
```

Output :

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

When I sort the duplicate_list using the sort() method, why the original_list is also getting sorted ?

I was expecting that the original list should not be affected.

Also when I use the **sorted()** function the original_list does NOT gets affected.

Comment: try this `duplicate_list=original_list[:]`

Comment: because you have two lists pointing to the same memory locations

Comment: Reminder: `=` never copies data.